# When I install own application in Quest 2 through SideQuest, This message shows "self-signed certificate in certificate chain" in SideQuest

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

When I install my own application in Quest 2 through SideQuest, This message shows "self-signed certificate in certificate chain" in SideQuest, and the app is not installed in Quest 2.

I create apk from Unity Game Engine and within Unity install XR development tools, etc things. This apk tries to install in Quest 2 with the help of SideQuest. Also successfully connected with SideQuest to Quest 2 and enabled developer mode, Quest 2 also connected with the Mobile application as well.

How to install apk into the Quest 2 device.